# $x^p - t$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_p(t)[x]$

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am actually trying to prove that $x^p - t$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p(t)[x]$. My approach is to consider a splitting field $E$ so that:
$$x^p - t = (x-\alpha_1)\dots(x-\alpha_p)=(x-\alpha)^p   \ \ \ \ \text{for some $\alpha$ in $E$}$$
Then assuming by contradiction that $x^p - t = f(x)g(x)$, then
$f(x) =(x-\alpha)^r$ with $r<p$. This implies that $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_p(t)$. Should this be a contradiction right? Why can't $\alpha$ be here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a duplicate of my question, but I'll post my own answer anyway: If $\alpha \in \mathbb F_p(t)$ then: 
$$ \alpha = \frac{F(t)}{G(t)} \ \ \text{where $F,G \in \mathbb F_p[x]$ }
 $$$$\implies \alpha^p = t = \frac{F(t^p)}{G(t^p)} $$
Then writing the coeffiecients for $F$ and $G$:
$$ t(a_0 + ...+a_mt^{pm}) = b_0 + ... + b_nx^{np}$$
And then $t$ is algebraic over  $\mathbb F_p$. Contradiction.